# How to add HTTP security headers?

Tags: php, apache, http, web, web-deployment

How can I add the following security headers to my website?

`X-Frame-Options` -  Protects against Clickjacking attacks
`X-XSS-Protection` -    Mitigates Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks
`X-Content-Type-Options`  - Prevents possible phishing or XSS attacks

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO, please head over to the help center and check the parts about asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking especially the article, of creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example would help improve your question here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options try this link

Comment: Please explain your problem properly (it will be more if you include code).
Also, you can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @johirpro i cannot include full web application here.. this was one of the Website Vulnerability Scanner Report issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two ways you can add these headers:

**Apache Conf or `.htaccess` File**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Frame-Options "DENY"
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>
```

The Apache/htaccess approach is most likely the preferred way. If you add it to your configuration file, which may be in your `httpd.conf` or it could be in a vhost configuration file (really depends on how the server is setup), you would place it within a `<Directory>` element. To use `.htaccess` the configuration for the site must have `AllowOverride All`. While it's pretty standard, you must have the `mod_headers` library installed in Apache as well.

**PHP**

```
header('X-Frame-Options: DENY');
header('X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block');
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
```

With the PHP approach, you will need to write this to every response, so if you do not have a bootstrap that can do this, I'd recommend leveraging either your apache configuration file or the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Glad it worked. You may want to take a stab at rewording your question. I kind of guessed what your issue is since we deal with a lot of WAS-enabled applications. Something like "How can I add security headers to my website?" would do that trick. Good luck!